# Legend in separate subplot and grid

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I have a collection of plots, arranged in two grids. In the left grid, I have one plot in the top (whole width) and two in the bottom (side-by-side). The two in the bottom are sharing legends. In my right grid, I want the legends, it is a lots of data series, and I would like to use the whole height of my figure.

The appearance of the data series are animated, but I would like the legends not to be.

My idea was to draw the time series in my right grid with legends, and hide the data series. But my only solution is ax.set_visible(False), which removes everything.

This is principally how the script looks like (simplified version):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

data = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
sett = np.array([1,2,3,4])

data1 = np.hstack((data,data*2, data*3, data*4))
data2 = np.hstack((3*data, 3*data/2, 3*data/3, 3*data/4))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array(data1), index = [1,2,3,4], columns = 
sett).transpose()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array(data2), index = [1,2,3,4], columns = 
sett).transpose()

gs1 = GridSpec(2,2)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right = 0.80, hspace = 0.05)
gs2 = GridSpec(3,1)
gs2.update(left=0.85, right = 0.98, hspace = 0.05)
figure = plt.figure()
plt.clf()
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,:])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1,0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[1,1], sharey = ax2)
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs2[:,0])
ax1.set_ylim(0,25)

label = ['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4']
ax4.plot(df1[1], df2[:])
ax4.legend(labels = label)

def make_frame(i):
    ct=sett[i]

    ax2.plot(df1[1], df1[ct])

    ax3.plot(df1[1], df2[ct])
    ax3.legend(labels = label)

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(figure, make_frame, frames = len(sett), 
                     interval =500, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

How can I remove the data series and keep the legend in gs2/ax4?

Don't bother I plot the first data series twice in ax2 and ax3 - it is ok in my original script. However - if someone can enlighten me on why, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need the lines in the bottom right subplot, what is the `data2` used for?

Comment: I use the lines in both the bottom subplots. It is in ax4 I want to hide the lines and only show the legend. (an ax1 in the top shows a series of images)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the desired output should be. Are you trying to put the legend at the place of `ax4` right now, but not have the plot shown in `ax4` at the moment.

My solution would be to not create `ax4` at all. Instead you can use `bbox_to_anchor` to move the position of the legend. Here I use the transform from `ax1` to establish a location in reference to `ax1` and I move the legend slightly past the right edge and at the top of `ax1`.

See ["legend guide" for more information](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

data = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
sett = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

data1 = np.hstack((data, data * 2, data * 3, data * 4))
data2 = np.hstack((3 * data, 3 * data / 2, 3 * data / 3, 3 * data / 4))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(data1), index=[1, 2, 3, 4], columns=sett).transpose()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(data2), index=[1, 2, 3, 4], columns=sett).transpose()

gs1 = GridSpec(2, 2)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.80, hspace=0.05)
figure = plt.figure()
plt.clf()
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 1], sharey=ax2)

label = ['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4']


def make_frame(i):
    ct = sett[i]

    ax2.plot(df1[1], df1[ct])

    ax3.plot(df1[1], df2[ct])
    ax3.legend(labels=label, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.), bbox_transform=ax1.transAxes)


ani = anim.FuncAnimation(figure, make_frame, frames=len(sett),
                         interval=500, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: using a [proxy artist](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles) to create all the legends before the animation starts

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

data = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
sett = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

data1 = np.hstack((data, data * 2, data * 3, data * 4))
data2 = np.hstack((3 * data, 3 * data / 2, 3 * data / 3, 3 * data / 4))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(data1), index=[1, 2, 3, 4], columns=sett).transpose()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(data2), index=[1, 2, 3, 4], columns=sett).transpose()

gs1 = GridSpec(2, 2)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.80, hspace=0.05)

figure = plt.figure()
plt.clf()
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 1], sharey=ax2)

ax1.set_ylim(0, 25)

labels = ['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4']
colors = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
proxies = [plt.plot([], [], c=c)[0] for c in colors]
ax1.legend(proxies, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1., 1.), loc="upper left")


def init_frame():
    pass


def make_frame(i):
    ct = sett[i]
    ax2.plot(df1[1], df1[ct], c=colors[i], label=labels[i])
    ax3.plot(df1[1], df2[ct], c=colors[i], label=labels[i])
    ax3.legend()


ani = anim.FuncAnimation(figure, make_frame, init_func=init_frame, frames=len(sett),
                         interval=500, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I know about the bbox_to_anchor solution, but I would like to have all the legends shown when the animation starts.  So the idea was to have a non-animated version in ax4, showing legends but not the data series/lines.

Comment: In this case, you don't need to actually draw the data on the axes. You can use what matplotlib calls "proxy artists" (https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) to create your legend. I've added an example in my answer

Comment: That didn't quite work neither. I don't get corresponding colors on my legend and data series. The funny thing is that the ax1.legend and ax3.legend is equal - but the colors in the lines are not the same...

Comment: I noticed, but then again, I don't think the colors matched in your original code either. To make sure everything matches, I think you'd be better off using a list of colors an passing these colors when you are creating your lines, so you know they'll match the proxy artist. An other problem you had is that without `init_func=`, `FuncAnimation` uses `make_frame()` to generate the first frame, which was causing a shift in colors. I updated my answer again

Comment: Thanks - this solution works. I have more than 10 lines, though - but hopefully I will solve this with another color map!

Answer (score 0):

I would create the line plots prior to animating anything. You can initialize them with empty lists and then set the data one by one.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

data1 = np.vstack((data,data*2, data*3, data*4))
data2 = np.vstack((3*data, 3*data/2, 3*data/3, 3*data/4))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

sett = np.arange(len(df1.columns))

gs1 = GridSpec(2,2)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right = 0.80, hspace = 0.05)

figure = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,:])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1,0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[1,1], sharey = ax2, sharex= ax2)

ax2.set_ylim(0,25)


lines1 = ax2.plot(*[[] for _ in range(len(sett)*2)])
lines2 = ax3.plot(*[[] for _ in range(len(sett)*2)])

label = ['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4']
ax1.legend(handles = lines1, labels=label, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05,1), loc="upper left")

def init():
    for line in lines1+lines2:
        line.set_data([],[])

def make_frame(i):
    ct=sett[i]
    lines1[i].set_data(df1.index, df1[ct])
    lines2[i].set_data(df1.index, df2[ct])
    ax2.relim()
    ax2.autoscale_view()

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(figure, make_frame, init_func=init, frames = len(sett), 
                     interval =500, repeat = False)
ani.save("anigif.gif", writer="imagemagick")
plt.show()
```

[image]